# What does it mean to flush to an ethereum address

Tags: contract-development

If ether is sent to a contract then flushed to an address what does this mean? Does it mean the contract sends the money to a recipient?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to contracts which collect Ether until some condition is met and then send it all in a single chunk onwards to somewhere else - either an EOA (Externally Owned Account) or another contract.

One example is a crowdsale contract - people send it Ether to buy tokens and then when the crowdsale ends someone initiates a "withdraw" transaction which flushes/sends all the contract's Ethers to predetermined address.